# How to save only date(yyy-mm-dd) in mongo using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose, format

I need to save the date in yyyy-mm-dd format, where has it adds timezone and the day value is decremented by one

Comment: You can use moment in your client to format your date https://momentjs.com/. It is a very great library

Answer (score 1):

In mongoose schema there is something called time stamps include it.

```
Schema({
    //your schema..
},{
    timestamps: true
})
```

When ever you extract the date and time it will be converted into local time zone and displayed. Still if you are not convinced you can add date object to your schema

```
date:{
    type: String,
    required: true
}
```

and you send the date object as follow:

```
var d = new Date();
var dateString = d.getFullYear() + '-';
if(d.getMonth()<9)
    dateString += '0' + (1+d.getMonth()) + '-';
else
    dateString += (1+d.getMonth()) + '-';

if(d.getDate()<10){
    dateString += '0' + d.getDate();
else
    dateString += d.getDate();
```

Use dateString for use in mongoose.

PS:Usage of timestamps is the best practice. It creates a createdAt and updatedAt fields which can be used in your front end to derive the dates.

Comment: Thanks for response. If I use date as string, It would be difficult for me to get the data based on Date - for e.g to fetch the data with tomorrow's date

Comment: no it won't. In your get request filter out only the date part which you require and then you can use your data.